# How to capture command output in perl using Net::SSH?

Tags: perl, ssh, perlnetssh

I've found lots of ways to use similar Perl `ssh` modules to capture `ssh` command line output (e.g. `Net::SSH::Perl`) but not how to do this with `Net::Perl`, which is what I want because it is packaged in Debian.

I found an example which shows some usage of `Net::Perl` but not enough for this novice to run `ls -1` on a remote system and send the output to my console, but I want to capture the output in a `@list`:

```perl
use Net::SSH qw(ssh issh sshopen2 sshopen3);
 
ssh('user@hostname', $command);
 
issh('user@hostname', $command);
 
ssh_cmd('user@hostname', $command);
ssh_cmd( {
  user => 'user',
  host => 'host.name',
  command => 'command',
  args => [ '-arg1', '-arg2' ],
  stdin_string => "string\n",
} );
 
sshopen2('user@hostname', $reader, $writer, $command);
 
sshopen3('user@hostname', $writer, $reader, $error, $command);
```

Comment: "_... which is what I want because it is packaged in Debian_"  -- It is very easy to install packages in Perl, in the system or as a user.  Why not consider something more established and actively maintained? I know of and have used [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH), which is well established and used (has a `capture` method btw).  And then you mention `Net::SSH::Perl`

Comment: Oof, just looked at the code, and `ssh_cmd` can deadlock if you provide `stdin_string`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$reader` and `$writer` arguments refer to file handles.

Here's an example of using a simple in-memory file handle to save the contents of the command output:

```perl
use Net::SSH qw/ sshopen3 /;

open my $memory_handle, '>', \my $var
    or die "Can't open memory file: $!";

my $command = 'ls -l';

sshopen3('user@hostname', undef, $memory_handle, my $error, $command);

while (my $output_line = <$memory_handle>) {
    print $output_line;
}
```

Comment: `while (my $output_line = <$memory_handle>)` should be `for my $output_line ( split /^/m, $var )` (or you could use a pipe).

Comment: @ikegami Actually I found `$var` is set to `undef` - I'm probably doing something wrong here. Oh and `foreach` is less performant than `while` for a handle.

Comment: Problem1: You didn't wait for the child to end. Need to waitpid the result of `sshopen3`.

Comment: Problem 2: The child can only write to Perl file handles that are backed by system file handles since it's another process. The handle you provided is not such a handle

Comment: Re "*foreach is less performant than while for a handle*", You don't have a handle, you have a string. The handle is for writing to the string, but at this point you're trying to get the info that's in the string.

Comment: (Also, `my $error` is a confusing way of writing `undef`.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say anything about being interactive, all you need is

```perl
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my @lines = capturex( ssh => $user_host, $remote_cmd );
```

Or if you want to capture both STDOUT and STDERR,

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ ssh => $user_host, $remote_cmd ],
   ">",  \my $stdout,
   "2>", \my $stderr;

my @lines = split /^/m, $stdout;
```